# What is torrified wheat?

Tags: ingredients, wheat, grain

What is torrified wheat and in what styles is it used?

Are there any restriction or special procedures you need to follow to when using torrified wheat?

Can you substitute torrified wheat with malted wheat?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Torrified Wheat has been heat treated (kind of "popped")to break the cellular structure, allowing for rapid hydration and allows malt enzymes to more completely attack the starches and protein. Torrified Wheat can be used in place of raw wheat in Belgian style Wit-Beers, also very good for adding body and head, especially to English ales.  Since it has not been malted, you can't sub it for malted wheat.  Because it's not malted, it needs to be mashed with a diastatic malt in order to convert the starches.

Comment: When a recipe calls for torrified wheat can you use malted wheat instead?

Comment: Well, yes and no....you'll get some "wheatiness" from the malted wheat, but it will be a different flavor than torrified.